# how to check for wordpress Query errors

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql or mysqli you can add this type of Query:

```
<?php

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, Insert into database itt (name) VALUES ($name)") or die(mysqli_error($con));

?>
```

What does wordpress do for this?

Or how does the code look?

Does it look like the code above?

Comment: You might want to try a debugging plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=debug+database&sort=

Comment: The Query Monitor plugin looks like the one you are seeking https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

A good pointer would be to enable debugging in WordPress. Add this to your `wp-config.php`: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`.

By default WordPress does not show much debug information. More on this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

You can install this plugin, [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/), it is not only query, you can also debug more information.